# How to add coocurrences in python seaborn in the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Basically, I want to reproduce the following plot in python (It is a scanned picture):

[image]

Until now I have the histogram but i didn't find how to reproduce the bottom part with those nice indicators.

My data looks like this:

```
id,date,Q38933,Q35805,Q767485,Q344873,Q188008,Q86,Q9690,Q40878,Q114085,Q474959,Q647099,Q485831,Q5445,Q1076369,Q3508755
1587150299663,22/04/2020,True,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,False
1587150082180,22/04/2020,False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
1587150149101,22/04/2020,True,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
1587150390220,22/04/2020,False,False,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
1587150481217,22/04/2020,False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
1587150599146,22/04/2020,False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
1587150729319,22/04/2020,True,True,True,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to create a similar plot using standard matplotlib. Both the symptoms and the cooccurrencies are sorted to get a layout. 3 subplots with shared x and y axes are combined to create the full plot.

The code supposes the input is given as a list of S symptoms for N individuals. A 1 represents a symptom that is present, otherwise 0.

Then, for each individual the S symptoms are combined into a binary number (via `matmul` with powers of two). These numbers are counted via `np.histogram`, and sorted from high to low.

Some details aren't fully worked out:

- xlabels and ylabels can be added at appropriate places
- probably the padding, the font sizes, the relative widths etc. need to be tuned to the concrete situation; it strongly depends on the number of symptoms and the number of cooccurrences to show how things stay most readable
- the image in the original post seems to have both gray and black vertical lines, but it is unclear by which criterion

The following code starts from a DataFrame similar to the one in the updated question. It then is converted to a 2D numpy array suitable for the subsequent calculations and plots.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

np.random.seed(13579)


def combined_number_to_list(cooc):
    ''' convert a binary number to a list of its powers of two
        e.g. 5 is converted to [0, 2] because 5 == 2**0 + 2**2
    '''
    return [i for i in range(20) if cooc & (1 << i)]

def cooccurrences_plot(symptoms, occurrences, num_cooc=30, min_cooc_count=1, color='C1'):
    ''' create a plot of cooccurrences
    :param symptoms: list of S symptoms
    :param occurrences: NxS array of occurrences of each symptom for a list of N individuals
    :param num_cooc: number of cooccurrences to show, maximum would be 2**S - 1
    :param min_cooc_count: minimum count of cooccurrences needed to be shown in the plot
    '''
    num_symp = len(symptoms)
    symp_sums = occurrences.sum(axis=0)
    symp_order = symp_sums.argsort()
    inv_symp_order = symp_order.argsort()
    combinations = np.matmul(occurrences, (2 ** np.arange(num_symp))[inv_symp_order])
    bins = np.arange(1, 2 ** num_symp + 1)
    values, _ = np.histogram(combinations, bins=bins)
    cooc_order = (-values).argsort()
    num_cooc = np.minimum(num_cooc, len(np.where(values >= min_cooc_count)[0]))

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row', figsize=(10, 5),
                            gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 4], 'height_ratios': [2, 3],
                                         'wspace': 0.25, 'hspace': 0.15, 'left': 0.04, 'right': 0.96})
    for ax in axs.ravel():
        for dir in ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']:
            ax.spines[dir].set_visible(False)
    axs[0, 0].axis('off')

    axs[0, 1].bar(range(num_cooc), values[cooc_order][:num_cooc], ec='white', color=color)
    axs[0, 1].tick_params(labelbottom=True, labelleft=True, length=0)
    axs[0, 1].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
    axs[0, 1].grid(True, axis='y', ls='--')
    axs[0, 1].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))
    axs[0, 1].axhline(0, color=color)

    axs[1, 0].barh(np.array(symptoms)[symp_order], symp_sums[symp_order], ec='white', color=color)
    axs[1, 0].tick_params(labelbottom=True, labelleft=False, left=False, length=0)
    axs[1, 0].invert_xaxis()
    axs[1, 0].grid(True, axis='x', ls='--')
    axs[1, 0].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))

    ax = axs[1, 1]
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=True, length=0)
    ax.set_xticks(range(num_cooc))
    ax.set_xticklabels(values[cooc_order][:num_cooc])
    ax.set_xlim(-1, num_cooc - 0.4)
    for i, cooc in enumerate(bins[cooc_order][:num_cooc]):
        ax.plot(np.full(num_symp, i), np.arange(num_symp), 'ob-', alpha=0.15, color=color)
        occ = combined_number_to_list(cooc)
        ax.plot(np.full_like(occ, i), occ, 'ob-', color=color)

N = 8000
symp_probability = np.random.uniform(0.05, 0.80, 15)
data = [[i + 1587150299663, '22/04/2020'] + list(np.random.binomial(1, symp_probability).astype(bool))
        for i in range(N)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'date', 'Q38933', 'Q35805', 'Q767485', 'Q344873', 'Q188008', 'Q86', 'Q9690',
                           'Q40878', 'Q114085', 'Q474959', 'Q647099', 'Q485831', 'Q5445', 'Q1076369', 'Q3508755'],
                  data=data)
symptoms = df.columns[2:]
occurrences = df[symptoms].to_numpy()
cooccurrences_plot(symptoms, occurrences, num_cooc=50)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: A simpler input example:

```
N = 500
symptoms = ['symptom '+l for l in list('ABCDEF')]
symp_probability = np.random.uniform(0.05, 0.80, len(symptoms))
occurrences = np.random.binomial(1, symp_probability, size=(N, len(symptoms)))
cooccurrences_plot(symptoms, occurrences)
```

EDIT (alemol): I have adapted the solution using my csv table:

```
canonical_symptoms_name = {
    'Q38933': 'fiebre',
    'Q35805': 'tos',
    'Q767485': 'fallo_respiratorio',
    'Q344873': 'sdra',
    'Q188008': 'disnea',
    'Q86': 'cefalea',
    'Q9690': 'cansancio',
    'Q40878': 'diarrea',
    'Q114085': 'congestión_nasal',
    'Q474959': 'mialgia',
    'Q647099': 'hemoptisis',
    'Q485831': 'linfopenia',
    'Q5445': 'anemia',
    'Q1076369': 'tormenta_de_citocinas',
    'Q3508755': 'síndrome_gripal'
}

canonical_symptoms_order = ['Q38933','Q35805', 'Q767485','Q344873', 'Q188008', 'Q86','Q9690','Q40878','Q114085','Q474959','Q647099','Q485831','Q5445','Q1076369','Q3508755']


symptom_names = [canonical_symptoms_name[code] for code in symptoms_order]
data = pd.read_csv('/data/table.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=True,
    dtype={'id': np.string_, 'date':np.datetime64}.update({s: np.bool for s in symptom_names}))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'date']+symptom_names,
                  data=data)
df = df.loc[:, (df != False).any(axis=0)]
symptoms = df.columns[2:]
occurrences = df[symptoms].to_numpy()
cooccurrences_plot(symptoms, occurrences, num_cooc=50)
plt.show()
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Yes is like that @JohanC, I posted part of my data. Tell me please if that csv table is convenient like that, or what do I have to chance to give it as input for your plot? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, i jus need to figure out how arrange the labels (symptom names) (could they be auto-adjusted?). I don't have any experience in pytplot and there are too many hardcoded numbers. Thank you JohanC

Comment: You can make `wspace` a bit larger to fit the wider symptom labels.  The xticks of the upper histogram don't need to be rotated when there are only a few co-occurrences. Maybe the unused symptoms need to be left out?  It seems hard to fit all possibilities into understandable function parameters. There are too many degrees of freedom (number of columns, number of rows, length of labels, length of counts, ...) to make something really auto-adjustable.

Comment: Yes `wspace=0.55` works well for my labels. I agree with you, unused symptoms need to be left out. I will filter the DataFrame so the plot function only gets the used ones.